# Deleting the topic immediately after sending a push notification

Tags: amazon-sns

We are planning using Amazon SNS to send push notification to our users. I am wondering what happens if I do the following programmatically (not important but with PHP SDK)

- Create a topic on the fly
- Subscribe 10000000 users
- Send a push notification to this topic
- Delete the topic immediately after sending the push notification

Will all subscribers receive the push notification?

Comment: Side note: It is possible that you will need to do 10m Subscribe calls as part of this process. SNS requests are charged at $0.50 per million, in addition to the delivery charge via Push of $0.50 per million. That would make the cost $10.

Comment: The 10 mil is just an arbitrary number. I am trying to find out what happens if I delete the topic while Amazon is sending the notifications. But thanks for the cost information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this.  Nothing in the docs say that SNS snapshots the topic when you publish, so don't rely on that behavior even if it seems to work.